# Conditionally constexpr variable

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have a bunch tests for a project which were originally written using Gtest, but I have since moved them into Microsoft's CppUnitTestFramework. In order to prevent having to rewrite all my tests, I made macros which follows how GTest does its tests -- for example, `EXPECT_EQ`.

Now, I am trying to eliminate all warnings generated by MsBuild, including those by the Code Analysis, which relate to using `constexpr` if available. In the tests, there's quite a few of these, since the expected value is usually a literal, although not always. So I have my own `EXPECT_EQ` which is as follows:

```
#define EXPECT_EQ( x, y ) { const auto _x = (x); const auto _y = (y); if ( _x == _y ) {} else { Assert::Fail(createFailMessage( _x, L" == ", _y ).c_str(), LINE_INFO() ); } }
```

This works fine; however, if it is called with `EXPECT_EQ( 7, getTime() )`, then I get a warning about how `_x` can be `constexpr`.

I know I can just create a separate macro like so:

```
#define EXPECT_CEQ( x, y ) { constexpr auto _x = (x); const auto _y = (y); if ( _x == _y ) {} else { Assert::Fail(createFailMessage( _x, L" == ", _y ).c_str(), LINE_INFO() ); } }
```

However, if I go back to GTest later, then I would have to fix all my tests to change `EXPECT_CEQ` to `EXPECT_EQ`.

So, my question is, is it possible to combine these two macros to make `_x` conditionally `constexpr` based on whether or not it can be `constexpr`?

PS: Yes, I know, macros bad.

Comment: What if you write `const auto _x = []{ return (x); }();`?

Comment: @Evg, you need to capture `x`. Also, I think lambdas are the right way to go here; since they're constexpr if possible. Make a lambda for testing equality and then immediately invoke it.

Comment: @AndyG, why? It's a macro. `x` could be `1+1`.

Comment: @Evg: That's a good point; it could be an expression or it could be a variable... but there's no way to tell.

Comment: @AndyG, I see. I have to capture variables that might be in `x`. Something like `[&]` might work in a restricted set of cases.

Comment: May I ask you why don't you just use `Assert::AreEqual`, directly? https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#general_are_equal

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o … that is a very good question for that example; although I also have less than, greater than, etc. versions

Comment: @Evg, your recommendation worked in most cases. Your follow up suggestion of using `[&]` was also necessary, since sometimes it is called with a variable.

Comment: @Evg, just recompiled all tests right now to see if that comes up or not, which it did not. They expected values are all literals and variables, with the occasional calling of a function of an object. I'll have to re-run code analysis on all tests to ensure it worked properly, which will take about 30 minutes though.

Comment: @Evg, just a follow up. Your solution seems to work -- at least I'm not getting warnings now :)

Comment: Up to you -- it did solve the issue, so it's an answer for my specific problem. Just include the `[&]` part ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a lambda that is invoked immediately:

```
const auto _x = [&]{ return (x); }();
```

`[&]` will capture every variable that might be used in the `x` expression.

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't be doing this just to prevent a warning. This just obfuscates code for a warning that isn't all that useful and ultimately it all depends on how good the compiler is at determining if it should be `constexpr` or not. The above case it just wasn't good enough, as it could still be `constexpr`.